# Is it possible to convert doc/docx to html using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-s3, apache-poi

I need to convert  doc/docx to html. I have files stored in Amazon s3. I need to view & edit it in browser. Right now, I am using Apache POI to convert doc/docx to html. And I am displaying the response on HTML editor(Jquery Plugin). It works but alignment/format changes. Also images not extracted. Any solution to fix image extraction & formatting issues, please refer or refer any Jquery/JS plugin for conversion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Doing a quick Google Search, I found these libraries: (I have not used, nor endorsed any of these)

- [docx2html](https://github.com/lalalic/docx2html)
- [mammoth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mammoth)

docx2html basic functionality:

```
var docx2html=require('docx2html')
docx2html(fileInput.files[0],{container:document.getElementById('a')}).then(function(html){
    html.toString()
})
```

mammoth basic functionality:

```
var mammoth = require("mammoth");


mammoth.convertToHtml({path: "path/to/document.docx"})
    .then(function(result){
        var html = result.value; // The generated HTML 
        var messages = result.messages; // Any messages, such as warnings during conversion 
    })
    .done();
```

I hope this was, at least, useful

Comment: mammoth works fine!

Comment: In mammoth library  tables and images are  not coming same as document.how to give proper format?

Comment: anybody have an example implementation of mammoth in a an express route that they can share?

Comment: mammoth has worked fine with Docx format but I have a problem it can't work with Doc format. can anyone have a solution?

Comment: @user2799827 Please see the following controller :)

```
exports.getDocumentDetails = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {


  
  let url = 'src/controllers/drive/Newsletter.docx';
  const result = await mammoth.convertToHtml({ path: url })

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: result.value,
    message: "Data loaded success!"
  });
});
```

Comment: Isn't there a better way of doing this, i used both but there were some issues in converting tables, math, charts, etc. i used this website (https://cloudconvert.com/docx-to-html) and it's great. Is there a way to find out what they are using ???