# How can we display data in a browser from Office.js API?

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

As explained in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41126116/1232087), using JavaScript/JQuery, we can convert `.docx` files to html. We need to display this html in the default browser. In our Office.js add-in for WORD, we can get an html from WORD document but we are not sure how we display it in the browser. For example: user clicks a button in the task pane of the Add-in==>Add-in gets the html from the active Word document==>the Add-in code displays that html in the default browser. **Question**: Is there any [Office.js API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/word-add-ins-reference-overview) etc that will help us display that HTML in default browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there's some reason why displaying it in a tab within the task pane isn't acceptable. (If it is, then that's something to consider.) There's also the [Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins). It's a window of the default browser, but it doesn't have the browser ribbon or menu bars. If you want a full blown browser window to open, I don't think that there is an API in Office.js that will do that. You might take a look at the standard window.open() method.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful (with good reference) specially at a time when there are less people to be able to response on the new `Office.js` Add-ins related topics as this is still new and still evolving.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways from which you can retrieve data from API and display on browser or DOM , in nodejs , the code would be somewhat like

```
//the npm library useful
 const request = require('request');
 request({
 url: 'www.example.com',
 json:true
 }
 , (error,response,body)=>{
  //your response will be in response object! Then you can easily display it to browser
 });
```